# Cryptographic Service Provider with C#/.net

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, cryptoapi

I have

- a third party document management system which can use custom cryptographic providers

and

- access to remote service (webapi/json), which implements all cryptography methods needed.

I have to implement my own csp (Cryptographic Service Provider) for signing/verifying. My CSP will not implement its own functions, just communicate with this actual server.
I downloaded "Cryptographic Provider Development Kit" and read a lot of cryptographic stuff and my understanding now is the following:

- csp is a legacy technology
- custom csp is written with c++
- custom csp dlls must be somehow "signed by Microsoft"

Am I right?
Can Cryptographic Service Providers be written with C#/.net?
Should I write a csp in 2021 or it's a bad idea?
Are there any step by step tutorials for C#?

Comment: I'm in the same situation, did you find anything?